# Navigate to PDF action for Orbeon button

Tags: orbeon

I have set up a custom process for the submit button on some of my forms as below:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.submit.App.*">
  require-valid
  then confirm(message = "Are you sure you would like to submit the form?")
  then suspend
  then review
</property>
```

Instead of going to the review page, I would like it to navigate to the pdf copy of the form (as is done with the pdf button). I have has a look at the documentation, but haven't found an action for this. I have found pdf-url, but not sure how to use this to do what I want.

I found the xbl that is used to generate the pdf url for the pdf button, but got stuck on $app and $form being undefined.

```
<fr:href-button
        xmlns:frf="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fr.FormRunner"
        model="fr-persistence-model"
        ref="instance('fr-triggers-instance')/pdf"
        href=
            "/fr/service/{
                $app
            }/{
                $form
            }/pdf/{{
                string-join(
                    (
                        xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/document/string(),
                        xxf:document-id(),
                        frf:filenameOrNull('pdf')[. != '']
                    ),
                    '/'
                )
            }}.pdf">


<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.submit.App.*">
  require-valid
  then confirm(message = "Are you sure you would like to submit the form?")
  then suspend
  then navigate(uri = "/fr/service/{ $app }/{ $form }/pdf/{ string-join( ( xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/document/string(), xxf:document-id()) , '/' ) }.pdf")
</property>
```

I've also noticed that it tries to confirm you want leave the page when it tries to redirect to the 404 of a pdf.

What would I replace `then review` with to go to the pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
navigate(
    uri =
        "/fr/service/{
        xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/app}/{
        xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/form}/pdf/{
        string-join(
            (
                xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/document/string(),
                xxf:document-id()
            ),
            '/')
        }.pdf"
)
```

There should really be built-in functions to access the app name, form name, and document id. But for now you can access them from that `fr-parameters-instance` instance. The `fr-parameters-instance` contains:

```
<app></app>
<form></form>
<form-version></form-version>
<document></document>
<mode>new</mode>
<uuid/>
```

You can force the data status to `safe` with the [`set-data-status`](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html#setdatastatus) action.

Comment: Thanks guys. That works. Had to make it one line as got an unexpected '\' after `/fr/service/{` when it was spread across multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

work for me

```
 uri =
        "/fr/{
        xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/app}/{
        xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/form}/pdf/{
        xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/document/string()} "
    )
```